# KQL: Check table of IPs against table of subnets

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel, microsoft365-defender

From a table with a column of IPs i would like to know which IPs are in a subnet from a table of which contains a column of subnets.

Attempt:

```
let IPs = SecurityAlert
| mv-expand parse_json(Entities)
| evaluate bag_unpack(Entities, columnsConflict='keep_source')
| distinct Address;
AzureIPTable
| extend ipv4_is_in_range(IPs, addressPrefixes)
```

Pretend `addressPrefixes` is a table of subnets in **AzureIPTable** and `Address` is a column of IPs in a table called **SecurityAlert**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

**`Firstly IP's Table:`**

[image]

**`Subnet Table:`**

[image]

Now use below **`KQL Query`** (to Check if IP is in  Subnet IP's, which are in another table ) like below:

```
let subnetTable = datatable(Subnet:string)
[
    "172.168.1.0/24",
    "10.0.0.0/24",
    "172.16.0.0/16"
]
|  summarize mylist = make_list(Subnet)
| extend new_column2 = 0
| sort by new_column2 desc;
let ipTable = datatable(IPAddress:string)
[
    "192.168.1.10",
    "10.0.0.5",
    "172.16.0.20"
];
let x=ipTable
| extend new_column2 = 0
| sort by new_column2 desc
| extend  rn=row_number()
|join kind=fullouter subnetTable on new_column2
|project-away rn,new_column2,new_column21;
let y = x
|mv-apply id= mylist to typeof(string) on (where ipv4_is_in_range(IPAddress,id))
|project-away mylist;
y
|join kind = fullouter x on IPAddress
|project-away IPAddress
|extend TESTCOL =iff(isempty(id),False,True)
|project-away id
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If present in range then gives true else gives false.

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA51RW2uDMBR%2091eEPik4p9J1l%20LDGBsMBhvUtzEkNscubS6SxKqjP36ptau1b0teDt85%20S4nDAzSVS7ApDhngBJEsLHX1u6iwx%200UVSsPOfTQfZMots4iGZ3QRSE1/F04vdoGHR3CHWDHRjNJs6Xs0NWinOs6A8g3jKqjdXjeAPZvu71PDsHjQFBkIA6W0pWcRHbwdA2tFQG5e1Zh4Bezh1mg9DyMsTrxyMhCrS%20yHF/zBGFoxQ3FxHi0AY4iDRJL/Mfn6c3SIlEyToTFc9BuTb1WlKBNlSQpKgYk5UBdfY1UgzpnF2p5BqW5grXuLVs/qA5rKOD7dY6a5wd317hsmQtoiQ5/oGRyLQlyMLtV7SXcutvUGBXup1mVGdUZAqL1WCfPiWeN3JxIJw77SCN1T3lafbUfxSj1wO8X1L6vEif3t9QQovCpRp4aVrX6vovmGnwU1XB2AIlv2vyIY/TAgAA).